# What are these hairy seeds?

Tags: trees, seeds

What the heck are these? I live in Florida and my dog swallowed these and then threw them back up. I washed them off to see what they might be. Covered in what looks like hair. The only trees I have are Queen palm, foxtail palm, 1 magnolia and 1 mimosa.[image]

Comment: It's palm, but I can't tell you which one. If you search on google the seeds of your two palms, it's probably from the queen palm

Comment: I found out these are from my Queen palm after the fruit ripens and turns orange. They are sweet so it attracts the dog to eat them. Keep them cleaned up or get rid of the Queen palm trees where the dog runs! They’re too tall to cut the fruit branches off so, I’ll have them removed!

Comment: @Rachel why don’t you post this as an **answer*? Self-answering your own question is perfectly fine on SE sites. Comments on the other hand are not the place for answers and are temporary by design. I’m sure other (future) users would love to learn from you.

Comment: I thought I did! Oh well!

Answer (score 1):

I found out these are from my Queen palm after the fruit ripens and turns orange. They are sweet so it attracts the dog to eat them. Keep them cleaned up or get rid of the Queen palm trees where the dog runs! They’re too tall to cut the fruit branches off so, I’ll have them removed!